# SQL where exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the total amount spent on transactions with a specific product sold during the period below.

```
    SELECT
  i.Customer,
  SUM(i.GrandTotal)
FROM
  transaction i
WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT
    1
  FROM
    transactionline il
    INNER JOIN product p
      ON p.ProductId = il.ProductId
  WHERE i.InvoiceDate >= '2016-09-01 00:00:00'
    AND i.InvoiceDate <= '2017-08-31 23:59:59'
    AND p.TableProductType = 25)
GROUP BY i.Customer;
```

My problem is that this query has a result the total amount spent during that period and not only transactions with that product involved

I started of with something like this :

```
SELECT
  i.Customer,
  SUM(i.GrandTotal)
FROM
  transaction i,transactionline il , product p
  WHERE i.InvoiceDate >= '2016-09-01 00:00:00'
    AND i.InvoiceDate <= '2017-08-31 23:59:59'
    AND p.TableProductType = 25);
```

But this also took much longer and the final result was wrong (cause of the multiplication caused by the join between transaction and transaction line)

Comment: The sub-query needs il/p condition(s) referencing i.

Comment: Add some sample data from table here for better understanding your problem

Comment: There must be a relation between tables `transaction` and `transactionline` for your query to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

few ways, all solutions using the with following as its data source directly before query, but substitute with your table name

```
with dat
as
(
select 1 tranid,'N' Tableproducttype,9.00 GrandTotal   union all 
select 1,'N',11.12 union all
select 1,'N',14.23 union all
select 1,'25',8.88 union all
select 1,'N',7.77 union all
select 1,'Y',6.66 union all
select 2,'N',3.21 union all
select 2,'N',19.13 union all
select 2,'Y',1.23 union all
select 3,'Y',4.31 union all
select 4,'Y',15.43 union all 
select 4,'Y',15.12 union all
select 5,'N',14.32)
```

1.) works using an IN

```
select tranid,sum(GrandTotal) GrandTotal
from dat
where tranid in (select tranid from dat where TableProductType = '25')
group by tranid
```

2.) using an exists

```
select tranid,sum(GrandTotal) GrandTotal
from dat
where exists (select 'x' from dat dat_inner 
              where dat_inner.TableProductType = '25' 
              and dat_inner.tranid = dat.tranid)
group by tranid
```

3.) using having, but could be slow

```
select tranid,sum(GrandTotal) GrandTotal
from dat
group by tranid
having sum(case when TableProductType = '25' then 1 else 0 end)>0 /* at least one product of type 25 */
```

Comment: Number 2 Worked fine!Thank you for the fast reply!

Comment: I am trying to insert the data into a new table  and although the select statement does not take long to complete (around 40 seconds) the insert takes very long. I dropped all constraints and indexes from the insert table but still takes foever.Any pointers as to why?

Comment: how many rows are you doing? maybe another session has a lock on it, but if that is not the case not sure why. any triggers on the table?

Comment: not many rows, around 300.000 and no i have no triggers for the table